# OGR2OGR empty geometry

Tags: ogr2ogr

I tried next command with geopackage, spatialite, geojson and others and they all process without any geometry. Shapefile just has DBF, geojson has , "geometry": null.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -skipfailures -progress -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT NAME,TYPE_CODE AS TYPE,CLASS,UPPER_VAL || ' , '||UPPER_UOM || ' , '||UPPER_Code || ' , '||UPPER_Desc as UPPER,LOWER_VAL || ' , '||LOWER_UOM || ' , '||LOWER_Code || ' , '||LOWER_Desc as LOWER,LEVEL_CODE AS LEVEL,CITY,STATE,COUNTRY,CONT_AGENT as CON_AGENCY,COMM_NAME,SECTOR,ONSHORE,EXCLUSION,TIMESOFUSE|| ' , '||GMTOFFSET|| ' , '||DST_CODE as TIMES,REMARKS FROM Special_Use_Airspace_Pending" path\special_use_airspace.shp path\Special_Use_Airspace_Pending.shp
```

Source data is located at: http://ais-faa.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/ac09bd0cf4164870bc7b68e60e8e09fb_0

Comment: With SQLite dialect you must select also "geometry".

Comment: This one looks ripe for @user30184, the asker or anyone to write a two sentence answer before it gets closed as "non-reproducible".